# Why i am getting the error that object has been used before a vaule is assigned?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

```
Dim EAM017 As EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient

If URL.Contains("http") Then

   Dim endPointHttp = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(URL)
   binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
   binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic

   EAM017 = New EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient(binding, endPointHttp)

   EAM017.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName
   EAM017.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password

End If

EAM017.FunctionalLocation(MyMTFuncLocRequest)
```

Now error is EAM017 has been used before a value is assigned.

The solution is to put it inside the if block but I don't want to do that and should be outside becuase more code is going to be there in future in the same way.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm assuming you get a warning and not an actual error. The reason you would get a warning is because you declare the variable outside of the `If` statement and only initialize it inside of that statement. However, you use the variable again after the `End If`. If your condition fails and you never enter the `If`, the attempted access after the `End If` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following

```vb
' EAM017 is declared, but not assigned to anything, thus is Nothing / null
Dim EAM017 As EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient
' your URL doesn't contain http
URL = "ftp://123.456.789.001"
' this condition is false ...
If URL.Contains("http") Then
    ' ... so this line doesn't happen
    EAM017 = New EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient(binding, endPointHttp)
End If
' EAM017 was never assigned, and is null. A null object exception will happen at runtime
EAM017.FunctionalLocation(MyMTFuncLocRequest)
```

Now you might say that your URL will always contain "http", then you don't need the `If`.

But if it's possible it won't contain "http" then you shouldn't be doing anything with a null object. You should either

- Add another case (where URL contains "ftp" for example) and assign the object in there accordingly
- Move the line `EAM017.FunctionalLocation(MyMTFuncLocRequest)` inside the `If`
- Move the line `EAM017 = New EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient(binding, endPointHttp)` outside the `If`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Not to the if statement and exit the sub if the requirements are not met. If they are met then just continue with the rest of he code.

To answer your question in the title. Not all code paths include the initialization of EAM017.

```
Private Sub OPCode(URL As String)
    Dim EAM017 As EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient
    If Not URL.Contains("http") Then
        'Notify the user and exit the sub
        Return
    End If
    Dim endPointHttp = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(URL)
    Binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
    Binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
    EAM017 = New EAM017_LNG_SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncService.SI_GetDetails_Out_SyncSoapClient(Binding, endPointHttp)
    EAM017.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = UserName
    EAM017.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password
    EAM017.FunctionalLocation(MyMTFuncLocRequest)
End Sub
```